# laravel view with selectRaw

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the sum of score where des = test1;

```
    $data=" ";
    $student = Student::find(1)->student;
    $scores = Score::where('school_id',$request->id)
    ->selectRaw('sum(score) as test, where des = Test1')
    ->groupBy('student_id','des')
    ->get();
    if($scores)
    {
      $i=1;
      foreach ($scores as $score)
      {
        $data .= '<tr><td>'.$i++.'</td>
                <td>'.$score->student['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$score->test.'</td>
                </tr>';
      }
      return Response($data);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any error messages? Warnings?

Comment: That `where` clause doesn't belong in the `selectRaw` statement. And `Test1` might need some quotes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

That where clause doesn't belong in the selectRaw statement. Also where clause when using with a string should be kept inside quote like `where des ='test1'`